# Linear movement in D3 force graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset of several weeks of nodes and links (some that persist but others that come and go over time) that I'm using a force layout to determine the positioning of.

By default when the forces move the nodes and links their initial velocity starts high and then reduces as the alpha decays and the graph settles.
I want the movement of these nodes and links to be linear (as possible) throughout.

I tried to achieve this by removing my tick listener that would move nodes and links per-tick and listening to the tick end event and transitioning the nodes and links to their final position i.e.

```
nodeSelection
  .transition()
  .duration(1800)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr('cx', d => d.x)
  .attr('cy', d => d.y);

linkSelection
  .transition()
  .duration(1800)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
  .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
  .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
  .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);
```

This works great for the nodes, however I want the links to move with the nodes if they should be attached to them whereas in my example they become detached.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm after either through a linear force movement, or modifying my more 'manual' transitions?